# Plain TeX (MiKTeX) installed Oct 7'20 on Windows 10 is not working as before (of Jan/Feb. 2019)

Tags: miktex, plain-tex, german

After a MiKTeX package update on 26.9.2020 Plain TeX (\input ngerman.sty) is no longer working as it used with my previous version MiKTeX 2.9 of January/February 2019, even after a fresh installation of MiKTeX
on 7.10.2020. I cannot get hyphenation and am getting errors with graphics (the fix of Phelype Oleinik of Oct 10'19 seems to work although I am still getting error messages). Can anybody give me a hint?

Example ref. hyphenation:

```
 \input ngerman.sty
  \hsize=15.9 true cm
  %
  Pforzheim war mit rund $24\,000$ Einwohnern um 1875/1880 nach
  Mannheim, Karlsruhe und Freiburg die viertgr"o"ste  -- zeitweise
  nach dem fast gleichgro"sen Heidelberg die f"unftgr"o"ste -- Stadt Badens
  (Einwohnerzahl 1900: $43\,373$, 1910: $69\,082$, 1925: $78\,859$).
  %
  \bye
```

Should hyphenate but doesn't!

Comment: Show a complete example that can be used for tests.

Comment: How did my name pop up here? ;-) Sorry, what fix are you talking about? Can I have a link, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really believe that something changed here, I get the same behaviour also with older texlive systems. The name of the language commands in ngerman.sty don't fit the names used in plain.

```
\catcode`\@=11
\expandafter\let\expandafter\l@ngerman\csname lang@ngerman-x-latest\endcsname
\catcode`\@=12
\input ngerman.sty


  \hsize=15.9 true cm
  %
  Pforzheim war mit rund $24\,000$ Einwohnern um 1875/1880 nach
  Mannheim, Karlsruhe und Freiburg die viertgr"o"ste  -- zeitweise
  nach dem fast gleichgro"sen Heidelberg die f"unftgr"o"ste -- Stadt Badens
  (Einwohnerzahl 1900: $43\,373$, 1910: $69\,082$, 1925: $78\,859$).
  %
  \bye
```

on miktex you probably need to compile with `pdfetex` instead of `pdftex` and need another language name:

```
\catcode`\@=11
\expandafter\let\expandafter\l@ngerman\csname lang@ngerman\endcsname
\catcode`\@=12
\input ngerman.sty


  \hsize=15.9 true cm
  %
  Pforzheim war mit rund $24\,000$ Einwohnern um 1875/1880 nach
  Mannheim, Karlsruhe und Freiburg die viertgr"o"ste  -- zeitweise
  nach dem fast gleichgro"sen Heidelberg die f"unftgr"o"ste -- Stadt Badens
  (Einwohnerzahl 1900: $43\,373$, 1910: $69\,082$, 1925: $78\,859$).
  %
  \bye
```

Comment: No help. Thanks anyway!

Comment: check in your miktex settings if the language has a different name (I checked only in texlive).

Comment: I checked on miktex, there only pdfetex seems to include the hyphenation patterns, and the name is `lang@ngerman` (at least in my miktex).

Comment: Thanks, Ulrike! I'm not that experienced with the TeX interna. Moreover, the documentation files don't apply to the present installation. Maybe I should pass

Comment: then why do you use plaintex? That is certainly not something for the non-experienced.

Comment: I have been using PlainTeX since 1987 and am quite familiar and satisfied with it.

Comment: I added a comment about miktex. For me this works.

Comment: Thanks, Ulrike! eTeX and pdfetex hyphenate with your fix!